# Python mysql connector rollback not working

Tags: python, mysql, innodb

I am writing a python script that does the following as a part a transaction.

1. Creates a new database.
2. Creates new tables using a schema.sql file.
3. Copies the data from the master DB to this new DB using `insert into select * from master.table_name...` like SQL statements.
4. Commits the txn, in the `else` block, if everything goes right. Rollback the txn, in the `except` block, if something goes wrong.
5. Close the connection in the `finally` block.

However, while testing, I found out that rollback isn't working. If an exception is raised after DB is created, even after rollback, DB is created. If an exception is raised after inserting data into a few tables with some tables remaining, calling rollback in the `except` block does not revert the inserted data. The script looks like this:

```
import mysql.connector
try:
    conn = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost', port=3306,
                                   user=USERNAME, password=PASSWORD,
                                   autocommit=False)
    cursor.execute("START TRANSACTION;")
    cursor.execute(f"DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS {target_db_name};")
    cursor.execute(f"CREATE DATABASE {target_db_name};")
    cursor.execute(f"USE {target_db_name};")

    with open(SCHEMA_LOCATION) as f:
        schema_query = f.read()
        commands = schema_query.split(";")
    for command in commands:
        cursor.execute(command)

    for query in QUERIES:
        cursor.execute(f"{query}{org_Id};")

except Exception as error:
    conn.rollback()
else:
    conn.commit()  # cursor.execute("COMMIT")
finally:
    if conn.is_connected():
        cursor.close()
        conn.close()
```

Below are the details of the setup

1. Python3
2. mysql-connector-python==8.0.32
3. MySQL 5.7
4. Storage Engine: InnoDB

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL, DDL statements aren't transactionable and cause an implicit commit when used within a transaction: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/implicit-commit.html   You'll need to manually drop the created database on error (which will drop the tables too).